# FBConnect and Permissions default to "optional"

Tags: facebook, ios5

I'm trying to request some mandatory permissions but for some reason the permissions dialogue presents them as optional.

I create an array of permissions:

NSArray *perms = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"offline_access", @"publish_stream", nil];

And then call authorize:

[[delegate facebook] authorize:permissions];

The dialogue shows "Example App has requested these optional permissions" with the options of deselecting the permissions along with buttons "Allow All" and "Allow None".

I need the standard non-optional permissions so I can track whether or not the permissions have been granted.

Comment: i have same problem , use in xcode 4.2